# Want to run more than one program in prestart script in package.json, and ignore exit error codes

Tags: typescript, eslint, yarnpkg, package.json, tsc

I want to run `yarn tsc` and `yarn lint` on my project to check for code errors on every `yarn start`.

This is my scripts property:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "expo start",
  "android": "expo start --android",
  "ios": "expo start --ios",
  "web": "expo start --web",
  "test": "jest --watchAll",
  "clean": "expo start -c",
},
```

So I set it up by adding the following:

```json
"lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx,.json",
"prestart": "yarn tsc && yarn lint"
```

However, when either one of them encounters an error, it stops right there and doesn't execute the script.

I then tried using `||`:

```json
"lint": "eslint . --ext .ts,.tsx,.json",
"prestart": "yarn tsc || yarn lint || exit 0"
```

But this doesn't work either, it just executes the first one and if it doesn't produce an error it skips `eslint`.

How could I configure a script to run multiple commands and ignore exit errors if any of them fails?

My main goal is to imitate the `create-react-app` template where it checks for error on every start... I just want to add the typescript check.

Comment: Use `;` to unconditionally chain

Answer (score 0):

> How could I configure a script to run multiple commands and ignore exit errors if any of them fails?

`&&` will only continue if the previous command succeeded and `||` will only continue if the previous command failed. You can do something like `(command1 && command2) || command2` as a workaround, which will run `command2` regardless of the output of `command1`, but this is ugly and does not scale well.

Depending on the OS you can use `;` (unix) or `&` (windows) to always run the second command. However this doesn't work if you expect to run this project on multiple machines, some of which have different underlying OSes.

Comment: Your first example using the AND/OR logic seems to be the most viable for now. But I agree it is not quite pleasant to eyes. Using the specific OS operators is a recipe for disaster. Tyvm anyway!